# turtlebot amcl mobile_base/goal problems

Tags: navigation, rviz, turtlebot, rosbridge, mobile-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that my turtlebot is not working right with amcl. I don't know what it is. Rviz shows my map, and turtlebot, and even what I think is feedback from the laser. (There are colorful clouds of light around what I suspect is the solid objects in the lasers path). I can also use my '/initalpose' publishing node to publish a starting position for the robot. This seems to work. I can watch rviz and see the robot move to a new position (...if I publish to /initialpose repeatedly).

I cannot get any response when I send the robot goal coordinates. I have tried '/move_base_simple/goal' and I have written code that sends coordinates to '/move_base/goal', that code using the Move Base Action Subscribed Topic. For me nothing works. My thoughts are that maybe the robot isn't localizing for the first time when I tell it where it is. Maybe there's a setting in amcl that adjusts the level to which the room map must match the laser scan in order for the initial localisation to take. Could this be? Does anyone have any clues about this??

EDIT: Here's more info. this is my rapp interface file. Maybe I've messed that up.

```
publishers: 
  - scan
  - /tf
  - tf_changes
  - /tf_changes
  - map
  - amcl_pose
  - move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/global_plan
subscribers: 
  - mobile_base/commands/velocity
  - initialpose
  - /initialpose
  - move_base_simple/goal
  - /move_base_simple/goal
  - move_base/goal
  - /move_base/goal
  - /move_base/goal/goal
services: 
  - save_map
  - rename_map
  - delete_map
  - publish_map
  - list_maps
```

I can also post rapp files and launch files. Looking at the interface file, I don't know when to include a leading '/' slash when identifying topics.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138241/turtlebot-amcl-mobile_base/goal-problems/) by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-03-10**:
Can you post the error message from the node?

**Comment by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on 2014-03-11**:
there is no error message on the laptop, and there's none on the computer on the robot, at least not a visible one. I looked in the .ros/log/ folder and under the topic 'app_manager-application-amcl' there was nothing. Is there somewhere else I should look?

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-03**:
Your problem seems to be same as one I have experienced. In my case, the problem is to forget to write a IP_Address of  workstation in /etc/hosts on my turtlebot2 PC. So, I could move my turtlebot2 with Rviz. That means turtlebot2 couldn't receive goal message without IP_Address of workstation.

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-04-03**:
can you start app manager with --screen option? it should log out app manager output via terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After this question I decided to revise my code alot. The new code had problems with amcl too, but I thought it had to do with the launch file, and specifically a remap in the launch file, not the goal position topic. I was right and got it to work to some degree. That was probably the problem here -- not a goal topic problem but a remapping problem. http://answers.ros.org/question/144181/turtlebot-amcl-hydro-rapp-scenario-goal-position/ This is a link to the question and answer that solved my problem.

---

Originally posted by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) with karma: 125 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0